# For People Who Have Weird ProjectionGlitch when they run EXE

Tags: visual-studio, directx-11

today i had a weird glitch that everything was working untill i built a exe of my project and then tried to run it. nothing worked when i ran the exe

Comment: It's totally fine to answer your own question, but please stick to the Q&A format: Ask an actual question in the question field, and then answer it yourself in the Answers section.

Answer (score 0):

First nothing worked, then when I moved the .lib files form my main project folder to the release version I got a gray window. Then I moved over the models and I got some weird glitch where it was like I never added my 3d projections. Then I looked at the pixel and vertexshader iso files that were created when I built. I then tried to replace them with the ones in my main project folder and everything worked perfectly.

For people with these problems:

1. Check that you have your libs.
2. Check that you have the models.
3. Look at what files were built and check if there is a version in your main folder because those are better.

main folder is where your project scripts are. My project is named SimGGE, so my project path is `source\repos\SimGGE\SimGGE`